# how get a link from attachment product in prestashop 1.5.x?

Tags: php, prestashop

The attachment is a picture and I want to show on the product page.How do I get the src for this picture?

```
<a id="single_image" href="{$img_dir}tabel_marimi/tabel_marimi.jpg"><img style="width:25px;height:20px;" src="{$img_dir}tabel_marimi/table_mini.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

src must be link to product attachment, not a general one for all products

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone runs into the same problem with Prestashop 1.6.x, this is how it's done:

```
{if $attachments}
    {foreach from=$attachments item=attachment}
        {$attachment.file_name} // This is the picture name
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Just point the `src` of the `img` tag to the route and append the `$attachment.file_name` at the end.

You can see all the properties of the `$attachment` by making `{print_r($attachment)}`.